# fmt custom formatting for vector of pairs

Tags: c++, fmt

Code snippet

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> myVec;
myVec.emplace_back(12,"A");
myVec.emplace_back(13,"B");
myVec.emplace_back(14,"C");
```

I would like to use following to produce output like "12=A|13=B|14=C"

```
fmt::format("{}", fmt::join(myVec, "|"));
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What happens if you try that?

Comment: right now it prints (12, "A")|(13, "B")|(14, "C"). I guess I need to provide  custom formatter like: class fmt::formatter<std::pair> but i don't know how

Comment: You may want to make your own pair equivalent `struct` or `class` that you can customize.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it as follows ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/q1sv9na5o)):

```cpp
auto v = std::views::transform(myVec, [](const auto& p) {
  return fmt::format("{}={}", p.first, p.second);
});
auto s = fmt::format("{}", fmt::join(v, "|"));
```

If you need to do it multiple times you could also put this in a function or provide a view type with a custom formatter.